# Replacing null when null doesn't exist in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = df.loc[:,'Project Code':'Business Analyst Support']
df2 = df.loc[:,'Closure':'PQQ Issue']
df2 = df2[['Gate 0','Gate 1','PQQ Issue','ITN Issue','Gate 2','Closure']]

progress_report = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis =1)

replacingNull = ['Business Analyst Support'] #for replacing empty string

progress_report[replacingNull] = progress_report[replacingNull].replace({'','-'})

progress_report[replacingNull].isnull()
```

The weird part is that the specific column business analyst support, has plentiful empty cells but doesn't display NaN when analysing dataframe (see image).

[The many empty rows that throw fall at .null() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ux6L.png)

[.isnull() returning False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAllm.png)

*How do I approach to replace those empty cells in Business Analyst Support column when simple str.replace method e.g. ' ', '', np.nan etc. is not working for me?*

Comment: if `''` is not what it is in the empty cell, what is in the empty cell? can you print it/ print the type of it/ print the `len` of it? I think your attempt to replace `''` with `np.nan` is a good one but if it doesn't work, then perhaps it is just something other than `''`.

Comment: Just realised the curly brackets. That was mistake 1 and now replace works. I wil check the length to make sure there is something anyway as I didn't see NaN.